# How to design and debug a custom I2C master-slave system?

Tags: motor, i2c, rotary-encoder, drone, debug

How to proceed, when in need of a custom I2C master-slave system?

What are the design criteria to apply?

What are the debugging tools one can use to troubleshoot problems?

Comment: This is a reference question. I have deleted a couple of comments that made this less obvious. (The question is answered by the asker).

Answer (score 11):

This tutorial I gave at the Embedded Linux Conference tries to answer the questions, providing links to more detailed description of the topics addressed and using the practical example of driving a 4WD drone, where an Arduino Mini Pro acts as slave and controls the 4 independent wheels.
The original document can be found [here](http://events.linuxfoundation.org/sites/events/files/slides/ELC%202016%20-%20I2C%20hacking%20demystified.pdf).

Note: This answer is currently work in progress, as I adapt the highlights from the link.

---

## Typical Applications of the I2C bus

- Interfacing with relatively slow peripherals. Ex: sensors, mechanical actuators.
- Controlling “fast” peripherals, that use other channels for exchanging data. Ex: codecs.

  In a PC, the Operating System usually interacts over I2C with:

  - temperature and battery voltage meters;
  - fan speed controllers;
  - audio codecs.

In case multiple bus controllers are available, peripherals are grouped by speed, so that fast ones are not penalized by slower ones.

---

## A quick introduction to the I2C bus - key features

- Serial bus.
- Only 2 lines: Serial CLock and Serial DAta (plus ground).
- 4 speeds: 100kHz, 400kHz, 1MHz, 3.2MHz.
- Typically, 1 master device and 1 or more slaves.
- Communications are always initiated by a master device.
- Multiple masters can co-exist on the same bus (multi-master).
- Open-Drain: both SDA and SCL need pull-up resistors.
- “Clock Stretching”

  - The master controls SCL, but a slave can hold it down (because open drain), if it needs to adjust the speed.
  - The master must check for this scenario.
  - A slave can get stuck and jam the bus: need for reset lines from the master to the slave.
- Typically 7-bit addressing, but also 10 bit is supported.
- Logical protocol: actual voltage levels are not specified and depend on individual implementations. Ex: 1.8V / 3.3V / 5.0V

Reference URLs:

- http://www.i2c-bus.org
- http://www.robot-electronics.co.uk/i2c-tutorial

## Example of Bus Configuration

[image: Example of Bus Configuration]

---

## Characteristics of the Protocol (simplified)

- 2 message types: *read* and *write*
- Start / Stop bit - represented as “[“ and “]” in the rest of the answer
- Address: 7 or 10 bits
- R/W bit: R = 1 / W = 0 Used to discriminate the type of message sent.
- Data on the bus: (Address << 1 | R/W)
- Registers as information handlers, within the selected device.

## Example of Bus traffic

[image: Example of Bus Traffic]
[image: Example of Bus Write Cycle]
[image: Example of Bus Read Cycle Part1]
[image: Example of Bus Read Cycle Part2]

---

## Custom Slaves

*Why create a custom I2C slave?*

- Desired sensor/actuator unavailable with I2C interface.
- Less unique addresses available than slaves needed.
- Desired custom functionality on the slave:

  - Semi-autonomous reactions to stimuli.
  - Filtering/preprocessing input data.
- Power optimization: custom “sensor hub” does the housekeeping while the main processor is idle.
- Realtime response to inputs.
- [your imagination here]

*How to design a custom I2C slave?*

- Define requirements (see previous slide).
- Choose microcontroller or microprocessor.
- Choose Scheduler or Operating System (if any).
- Define communication sub-protocol:

  - Define parameters and commands to be exchanged.
  - Organize them into “registers” and choose a free address.

---

## Design of the I2C Master

Key design criteria:

- Weight/Dimensions.
- Required computational power and average latency.
- PC-like device

  - Embedded device, typically headless.
  - Preferred programming language: interpreted vs compiled.
- Availability of busses/gpios for driving the slave(s):

  - GPIOs only: bitbang the protocol
  - I2C: user-space application vs kernel driver.
  - No GPIOs/I2C interfaces available: USB to I2C adapter.

---

## Debugging: Divide and Conquer

Take direct control of the bus with an ad-hoc device. 
Examples:

- Bus Pirate (useful also for other busses)
- USB to I2C Master adapter, also based on the FTDI FT232R chip.
- Custom device (could be a separate project).
- Snoop the bus with a logic analyzer or a scope/advanced meter.
  Examples:

  - sigrok/pulseview with compatible logic analyzer
  - 2-channels standalone scope/meter
  - Use slave-specific In Circuit Debugger/In Circuit Emulator.

    Example:
    AVR Dragon for AVR chips (Arduino UNO, Nano, Mini, MiniPro)

---

## BUS Pirate

[image: Bus Pirate]

- Primarily for development purposes.
- Can both sniff the bus and drive it.
- Console interface over serial (ttyACM) port, including macros, or programmatic access for several programming languages.
- Built-in pullup resistors and voltage sources (5V / 3.3V)
- Supports many other protocols.
- References: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bus_Pirate), [main page](http://dangerousprototypes.com/docs/Bus_Pirate)

---

## USB to I2C Adapter

[image: usbtoi2c]

- Small footprint.
- Suitable for permanent installations.
- No need for special connections on the host: it can be used to interface with a typical PC.
- Variant available that is also SPI-capable.
- No console interface, only serial binary protocol.
- Requires [protocol wrapper](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/22069/how-to-operate-under-linux-an-usb-to-i2c-adapter-based-on-the-ftdi-ft232r).
- Reference: [protocol](http://www.robot-electronics.co.uk/htm/usb_i2c_tech.htm)

---

## sigrok and pulseview

sigrok(bakend component) logo

[image: sigrok]

pulseview (visualizer) example

[image: pulseview]

Example of low end logic Analyzer

[image: saleae]

- De-facto standard for PC-driven measurements on linux (but available on other OSes too).
- Support for vast range of logic analyzers, scopes and meters.
- Various protocol decoders, including I2C.
- Useful for visualizing the logical signals and debugging protocol errors.
- Even very low end, inexpensive HW can provide a whole new dimension to debugging.
- References: [sigrok](https://sigrok.org), [pulseview](https://sigrok.org/wiki/PulseView), [supported hardware](https://sigrok.org/wiki/Supported_hardware)

---

## Example: steering a 4WD drone

Prototype built using 2 Arduino Mini Pro.
[image: Drone]

---

## What does the slave do in the example?

The I2C slave:

- Controls the amount of torque applied to each wheel.
- Controls the direction each wheel spins.
- Measures  the rotation speed of each wheel through an optical encoder (Odometer).
- Exposes the parameters above to the I2C Master.

[image: Slave Role]

High level block diagram of the I2C Slave.

---

## Selecting the Slave: [Arduino Mini Pro](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardProMini)

[image: MiniPro]

- Enough pins/functions to provide for each wheel:

  - 1 PWM output with independent configuration of the duty-cycle.
  - 1 GPIO for registering odometer input as IRQ.
  - 2 GPIOs for selecting:

    - Forward
    - Reverse
    - Idle
    - Lock
- I2C HW block for interrupt-driven i2c exchanges.
- Dedicated pins for SPI-based programming.
- Small footprint.
- Low Cost.
- The board layout of the clone represented in the picture is optimized for mounting on a DIL socket.

---

## Slave-specific ICD: [AVR Dragon](http://www.atmel.com/webdoc/avrdragon/)

[image: AVR Dragon]

- Supports various programming modes, included SPI programming, through [AVRDude](http://www.nongnu.org/avrdude/).
- Doesn’t interfere with normal AVR operations, so it can be left plugged into the system.
- [After enabling debugWire interface, it allows configuring HW/SW breakpoints, by a dedicated backend for gdb/ddd.](http://www.larsen-b.com/Article/315.html)

---

## Selecting the OS: [ChibiOS](http://www.chibios.org/dokuwiki/doku.php)

[image: ChibiOS]

- RTOS: preemption, tasks, semaphores, dynamic system tic, etc.
- Small footprint: link only used code/data.
- Distinction between RTOS and BSP through HAL.
- GPLv3 for non-commercial use.
- Actively developed, but already mature.
- Supports 8bit AVR.

However it had limited BSP support for AVR, lack of:
 - interrupts driver for AVR GPIOs (added).
 - I2C support for AVR slave mode (custom).
Which had to be developed separately as part of the [Drone SW for the AVR](https://github.com/igor-stoppa/ChibiOS/tree/car/).

---

## Defining the Communication Parameters

*For each wheel:*

- **Duty Cycle** of the PWM signal used to drive it - 1 byte.
  0xFF = max torque / 0x00 = no torque.
- **Direction** of rotation - 1 byte.

  - 0x00 = idle
  - 0x01 = reverse
  - 0x02 = forward
  - 0x03 = locked
- **Average period** in between slots of the optical encoder - 2 bytes.

  - Writing anything resets the measurement.
- **Parameter Index** - 1 nibble:

  - 0 = Duty Cycle
  - 1 = Direction
  - 2 = Average Period
- **Wheel indexes** - 1 nibble:

  - 0 = Left Rear
  - 1 = Right Rear
  - 2 = Right Front
  - 3 = Left Front
  - 4 = All

---

## Sub Protocol: Defining the Registers

**Register format:   0xαβ**
 - α = Parameter Index
 - β = Wheel Index

**Address** (chosen arbitrarily): 0x10

**Bus Pirate format:**
 - [ = start bit
 - ] = end bit
 - r = read byte
 - address times 2 (left shift 1), for R/W bit

---

## Example - in Bus Pirate Format

**[   i2c_addr   reg_addr=(parm,wheel)   reg_value  ]**

```
[0x20 0x20 0x02]  Left Rear Forward
[0x20 0x21 0x01]  Right Rear Backward
[0x20 0x22 0x01]  Right Front Backward
[0x20 0x23 0x02]  Left Front Forward
[0x20 0x14 0xFF]  Wheels set to max torque
```

*The car spins clockwise.*